# Can I restore an application by application switching to it?

Tags: macos, keyboard

When you <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to an application that is minimized it doesn't bring it forward, is it possible to make it so it gets restored?

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you want to hack it by creating a script that always runs and checks if the front application has a minimized widow. I can write an Applescript that would do this if you want ? Otherwise, have you tried hiding the window/app instead of minimizing it ? (command+H)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the minimized application selected, start holding the <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> key before you release the <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> key.

Comment: Well the certainly works in brining the window forward, though a pre-requisite is that I need to be aware the window is minimized to begin with which is to bad.